# Design disappear while running scriptmanager message box

Tags: c#, asp.net, scriptmanager

Am using the below code to show the error message. It's working but i have a problem, design 
disappear while running scriptmanager  message box. I can't able to fix this.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
                this.GetType(), "PopupScript", "javascript:Editalertmessage('" + DeleteUS + "');", true);
```

Comment: is there an updatepanel on your page?

Comment: yes i have a updatepanel with UpdateMode="Conditional" property

Comment: When are you running this code? On a buuton click?

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(yourupdatepanel, this.GetType(), "PopupScript", "javascript:Editalertmessage('" + DeleteUS + "');", true);
```

Comment: see my updated answer...should work now. use `RegisterClientScriptBlock`

Comment: The entire page disappear. Only the message box appear.